# Query One to Many Relationship SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to query the users based upon their skills from these tables.

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    skills = db.relationship('Skill', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
```

---

```
class Skill(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'skills'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    skill = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

i tried this in **User** table and got this error.

```
@classmethod
def users_by_skill(cls, skill):
    return User.query.join(Skill).filter(skill.skill).all()
```

---

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'skill'
```

Where i am missing badly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You define the following class method:

```
@classmethod
def users_by_skill(cls, skill):
    return User.query.join(Skill).filter(skill.skill).all()
```

You are probably expecting to use this function like so:

```
users = Users.users_by_skill('nunchuk')
```

That means the `skill` argument in `users_by_skill` is a string. Then, you try to use `skill.skill`, which essentially is like doing `'nunchuk'.skill`. Python does not have a `skill` attribute on the string class, hence the error.

The [`filter`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) function actually takes a `Criteria` object. In other words, you don't pass it a value like `"filter"`, you instead pass it a criterion that represents the notion of "the skill column on the Skill table must equal 'nunchuk'". You can do this using syntax like the following:

```
@classmethod
def users_by_skill(cls, skill_name):
    return User.query.join(Skill).filter(Skill.skill == skill_name).all()
```

Comment: I am trying to query users by supplying the skill to the function.

E.g `User.users_by_skill('python').all()`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I put `Skill.users_by_skill`, which was not what I meant. I didn't get a chance to actually test this code, and I am a bit rusty on SQLAlchemy so please let me know if you used a different method and I'll update the answer.